# Oracle Function required with certain logic to implement in Spotfire

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have created a Function from Oralce DB and used it as input to Spotfire report. The reason why i used a function instead of view is because the parameters had some complex logic operations and i was not able to get that done in a view.

Coming to the report i have built. Currently i am using 2 parameters in the function and i am taking both the values from Spotfire text area in Data on Demand mode. Issue is that unless i enter values for both parameters i wont get the output. My requirement is that i need to add few more parameters for the report which i can but i need to set up the function and the settings in Spotfire such that if 5 parameters are there , if users enters one value for just one parameter report should run for that parameter. So the Functions needs to be in such a way that if value is entered that should be taken and if its left empty then that should not be considered. leaving the Spotfire part if the Function is built with the specifics mentioned by me i can implement it directly.

I have got different solutions from everywhere and i am not able to implement anything properly. I am updating all the examples and need help in figuring out the right one and correcting it or to do it in a completely different manner

**Code Type 1:**

```
create or replace function Function_test(p1 varchar2='',p2 varchar2='',p3 varchar2)
      return SYS_REFCURSOR as
      my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    begin
      open my_cursor for

    select distinct

               x.c1
               x.c2
               x.c3
               from x
               where x.c1=p3
               and (p1='' or x.c2=p1)
               and (p2='' or x.c3=p2);

      return my_cursor;
    end;
```

The above code seems to be an example from MSSQL and i am able to get the logic but dont know the right way to implement in Oracle. When i tried i just got lot of errors.

**Code Type 2:**

```
create or replace function Function_delete(param1 Varchar2, param2 varchar2)
  RETURN Varchar2 IS
  ssql varchar2(3000);
  test varchar2(1000);
begin
  ssql := 'select col1,col2 from table_x';
if  param1 is null and param2 is not null then
  ssql := ssql || ' Where col2='''|| param2 ||'''';
  end if;
  if  param1 is not null and param2 is null then
  ssql := ssql || ' Where col3= ''' || param1 ||'''';
  end if;
  if  param1 is not null and param2 is not null then
  ssql := ssql || ' Where col3 = ''' || param1 || ''' and col2='''|| param2 ||'''';
  end if;
  dbms_output.put_line(ssql);
  execute immediate ssql into test;
  return test;
--EXCEPTION
 -- WHEN OTHERS THEN
  -- return 'Hello';
end Function_delete;
```

In the above example i am not able to implement the logic right in Spotfire cos it requires columns to get the data. Ultimately i need a code that accepts no of parameters that are given by the user rather than working only when all parameters are given. It needs to have columns visibly displayed since that way i can implement the same in Spotfire Reports.

Comment: select distinct  x.c1 ... commas missed between columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
create or replace function Function_test(p1  in varchar2,p2  in varchar2,p3  in varchar2)
      return SYS_REFCURSOR as
      my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    begin
      open my_cursor for 
    select
    1
    from
    dual
    where 1=1
    and '1'=p1
    and '2'=p2
    and '3'=p3 ;

      return my_cursor;
    end;
```